# Pass or Fail in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I want to compare the score in multiple columns against a fixed number to give a pass or fail for each column and overall i.e if one column is a fail, the whole series is a fail. 
For example each score should equal or exceed 150 to pass. I've set the colours to change in each cell, but also want a Pass/Fail indicator for the whole series of columns.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please edit your question to include sample data and expected outcomes. This will help you get better answers.

Comment: for color you can use this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how your data is laid out, but this shows how it can be done.

[image]

The formulas are:

H1: `=IF(MIN(A1:E1)>=150,"Pass","Fail")`

H2: `=IF(MIN(A:A)>=150,"Pass","Fail")`

`MIN` returns the lowest value found in the range and ignores blank cells and text.

If you wanted a visual flag, this could also be used for Conditional Formatting. For example, the equivalent formula for Row 1 would be `=MIN(A1:E1)>=150` for Pass and `=MIN(A1:E1)<150` for Fail.